# Python Blackjack game questions

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm programming a type of Blackjack game. In this game I want to make it so the dealer and the player each have 100 health and if they lose a hand then they lose 10 health. This goes on until one of them reaches 0 health. I can't figure out how to add health to the game.

Below is the game as of right now:

```
import random
newgame = 0

def get_card():
    #I did random from 1,11 to reduce card counting. 
    return random.randint(1, 11)

def player():
    blackjack = False
    total = 0

    print('************ YOUR TURN ************')

    card1 = get_card()
    card2 = get_card()
    total = card1 + card2

    print("Cards: " + str(card1) + " " + str(card2))
    print("Total: " + str(total))
    if total is 21:
        blackjack = True

    while total < 21:
        option = raw_input('Type "S" to stay  or "H" to hit ')
        if option == 's' or option == 'S':
            break
        card1 = get_card()
        print("\nDraws: " + str(card1))
        total += card1
        print("Total: " + str(total))
    return total, blackjack


def dealer():
    print("\n********** DEALER'S TURN **********")

    total = 0
    card1 = get_card()
    card2 = get_card()
    total = card1 + card2

    print("Cards: " + str(card1) + " " + str(card2))
    print("Total: " + str(total))
    while total <= 16:
        raw_input('Press <enter> to continue ...')
        card1 = get_card()
        print("\nDraws: " + str(card1))
        total += card1
        print("Total: " + str(total))
    return total

def main():
    play_again = True


    while play_again:
        player_total, blackjack = player()
        player_wins = False
        dealer_wins = False 
        if blackjack:
            print('Blackjack!')
            player_wins = True


        if player_total > 21:
            print('Bust!')
            dealer_wins = True

        if player_wins is False and dealer_wins is False:
            dealer_total = dealer()
            if dealer_total > 21:
                print('Bust!')
                player_wins = True
            elif player_total > dealer_total:
                player_wins = True
            else:
                dealer_wins = True

        print("\n********** GAME OVER **********")
        if player_wins:
            print('You win!')
        elif dealer_wins:
            print('Dealer wins!')
        while True:
            again = raw_input('Type "P" to play again or "Q" to quit: ')
            if again.upper() == "Q":
                print("Game ended.")
                play_again = False
                break
            elif again.upper() == "P":
                break
main()
```

Comment: What have you "tried" regarding adding the "health thing", and what problem(s) did you have doing so?

Comment: i made variable health and set it to 100 then tried making it so its - 10 everytime either the dealer or player loses health but it didnt work so im lost.

Comment: And where is that code?

Comment: i removed it from the code so it would work for you guys. It would not run with what i had in there.

Answer (score -1):

You would definitely want to use an object oriented approach if you want to include several players. Refer to this page if you are unfamiliar with it: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_classes_objects.htm

If you want to just add it to the main function, I would suggest adding a `hp = 100` variable. Everytime it's a bust, just deduct 10 from it. If `hp == 0`, end the game.

Answer (score -1):

just set health to 100 for player and dealer and just take off 10 each time they lose. just decrement player health under dealer wins and dealer health under player wins. fairly simple really